# Pronunciation of fastidious

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

According to OALD and some other dictionaries, [fastidious](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fastidious?q=fastidious) is pronounced as /fæˈstɪdiəs/ in BrE. But when I listen to the pronunciation, it sounds /fəˈstɪdiəs/ to me. Which is correct in BrE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say /fæˈstɪdiəs/. But I probably wouldn't notice if somebody else said /fəˈstɪdiəs/.

I never know quite what people mean by "correct", but I don't find either odd or unacceptable.